# How to get background image showing on DOMPDF generator

Tags: css, pdf, background-image, dompdf

So far, I've been trying to work with this code:

```
<style>
    body {
        background-image: url(http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/myImage.jpg);
        background-size: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
</style>
```

Yet this doesn't render an image on the generated PDF.

A plain image tag in the body that's formatted this way, works and shows up fine:

```
<img src="/home/example/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/myImage.jpg">
```

Does anyone know why this is? What can I do to get the background image to actually show on the generated pdf?

**UPDATE**:

I've now tried to base64_encode() all possibilities of links.. meaning I've passed,

/home/example/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/myImage.jpg

http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/myImage.jpg

/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/myImage.jpg

These ^ combinations through the base64_encode() function, and none of them have worked to display a background image yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## A more flexible solution

This way you do not have to know the relativeness of the directory generating the PDF.

`..include setup.dompdf.php in your generator script`

```
<?php 

    $webRoot = '/var/www/html/';

    $dompdf = new Dompdf($this->dompdf_options);
    $dompdf->setBasePath($webRoot);

?>
```

Then you can reference any file in css relative to the web root from any script you are generating the pdf.

```
<style>
    body {
        background-image: url(wp-content/uploads/2016/04/myImage.jpg);
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 8):

I know this question is old, but there is always room for other answers.

You can try to use base64. Here is the code:

Get image content.

```
$data = file_get_contents('absolute/path/to/background-image.jpg');
```

Convert it to base64.

```
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
```

In CSS use it this way.

```
body { background-image: url(<?php echo $base64 ?>); }
```

But remember that background-size property doesn't work properly, at least as far as i tried.

Comment: After trying the other methods, this one worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Can you .svg type?

Comment: this solved for me (dompdf 2.0.4) 
`$data_img_bg = file_get_contents($path.'/img/topo.png');
$base64 = 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($data_img_bg);
// in css
background-image: url(<?php echo $base64; ?>)`

Answer (score 2):

I've figured it out. Something I failed to realize was that the html that's being put together was located in a folder that my wordpress theme folder, so in order to access the image I needed, I needed to go back a couple of directories based on where that html file was in my file structure. I was trying to access an image attached to a post from the media library.

The solution was simple:

```
background-image: url(../../uploads/2016/04/myImage.jpg);
```